# Different behavior of width and margin in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have two floated elements in 960px container

I've testing these elements in different sizes, everything is ok in chrome but in **Firefox** elements don't stay to together in some situation.

**Passed:**

(Width: **479.04px** * 2) + margin-left: **0.48px** + margin-right: **0.48px** = **960px**

(Width: **477.12px** * 2) + margin-left: **1.44px** + margin-right: **1.44px** = **960px**

http://lukepeters.me/csspad/X5EKgU595 *(See in Firefox)*

**Failed:**

(Width: **478.08px** * 2) + margin-left: **0.96px** + margin-right: **0.96px** = **960px**

(Width: **473.28px** * 2) + margin-left: **3.36px** + margin-right: **3.36px** = **960px**

(Width: **468.48px** * 2) + margin-left: **5.76px** + margin-right: **5.76px** = **960px**

http://lukepeters.me/csspad/eWPNEF594 *(See in Firefox)*

Any suggestions?

Comment: You are always going to get iffy results using fractions of pixels, which browsers can't display. They will have to round up or down.

Comment: Yes understand it, but .08px .06px are repeated in failed results, I want to know more about this behavior ;)

Comment: I guess it's interesting to play around with this, but really, I don't see the point, as pixel fractions can't be displayed, so the browser will have to do something with them. If you want reliable results, just don't use them.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers often add default margins or paddings to elements. To be safe, always use a reset CSS at the top of your CSS file:

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Dark Ashelin, but this is deeper than reset CSS, this is something about rendering pixels fractions in browsers :)